# How do I get my Javascript to show just one spotlight centred on the mouse?

Tags: javascript, css

At the top of my [website](http://www.trinity-international.com) you can see that I have an animation at the top, I'm having trouble getting it to show just one spotlight that is centred on the mouse along with having the text shadow effect being centred on the mouse also.

I have found that by zooming in on the browser the centring issue is fixed but if possible I would rather not set a fixed zoom level for visitors.

Below I have attached the CSS followed by the JavaScript that I have used:

The CSS:

```
#text-shadow-box {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 350px;
    background: #666;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: none;
    border: 1px solid Black;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    -webkit-user-select: none;
}

#text-shadow-box div.wall {
    position: absolute;
    top: 175px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

#tsb-text {
    margin: 0;
    color: #999;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 80px;
    line-height: 1em;
    height: 1px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}

div.wall div {
    position: absolute;
    background: #999;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 150px;
    left: 0;
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
}

#tsb-spot {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(/spotlight.png) top center;
}
```

The JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" charset="utf-8">

var text;
var spot;

///window.onload = init;
init();

function init() {
text = document.getElementById('tsb-text');
spot = document.getElementById('tsb-spot');

document.getElementById('text-shadow-box').onmousemove = onMouseMove;
document.getElementById('text-shadow-box').ontouchmove = function (e)    {e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation(); onMouseMove({clientX:     e.touches[0].clientX, clientY: e.touches[0].clientY});};

onMouseMove({clientX: 300, clientY: 200});
}


function onMouseMove(e) {
var xm = e.clientX - 300;
var ym = e.clientY - 175;
var d = Math.sqrt(xm*xm + ym*ym);
text.style.textShadow = -xm + 'px ' + -ym + 'px ' + (d / 5 + 10) + 'px  black';

xm = e.clientX - 600;
ym = e.clientY - 450;
spot.style.backgroundPosition = xm + 'px ' + ym + 'px';
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your current implementation, you are using an image for the spotlight, found on this line:

```
background: url(http://www.zachstronaut.com/lab/text-shadow-box/spotlight.png) top center;
```

A much better implementation would be to add a `<canvas>` element instead where your title is currently on your website. You can use `CanvasRenderingContext2D.createRadialGradient()` to create a spotlight effect: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/createRadialGradient.

You can also see some similar implementations of what I am recommending here:

https://jsfiddle.net/4Ezkg/

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-mouse-coordinates/

Comment: Great, so I create a canvas, then on the line which currently has the url to the image I replace it with a canvas id?

Comment: I would change the HTML element `<div id="tsb-spot">` to a `<canvas>`. `<canvas>` elements and the accompanying Javascript can get quite complicated fairly quickly for those new to `<canvas>` elements. Best of luck with the website! Cheers.